# Turbulenz engine not installed error but it works for samples

Tags: turbulenz

I try to build my first app using Turbulenz engine but it won't display on my localhost - i keep getting error "Turbulenz Engine not installed. You need it to play 3D games in your browser."

Samples work! Problem persist only in my project. I installed sdk, python27, and path is configured. I was following docs tutorial: http://docs.turbulenz.com/starter/getting_started_guide.html#creating-a-turbulenz-application
(i wrote same js like in this tutorial, added application from localserverl:8070.

But i keep getting error engine not installed. Samples though work fine.

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant code from your project?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turbulenz plugin was disabled in chrome plugins. When i enabled it, it all works.